# Adding HTML controls to SharePonint 2010 quick launch

Tags: sharepoint

We are migrating Lotus Notes application to SharePoint 2010. There are around 200 views on navigation pane of Lotus Notes. In order to provide similar kind of look and feel on SharePoint I am thinking to add dropdown on quick launch of my site.

Is it possible to add HTML controls like dropdown and add a functionality to navigate to respective view? Or else what could be the better solution for this case?

Thanks,

Pratima

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASP.NET placeholders available in the masterpage to host a control or WebPart beside the Quick Launch. The actual QuickLauch is generally customized by JavaScript unless you want to replace it with a completely new class.